# Load the content of a page in a div using history (pushState, popState)

Tags: jquery, browser-history

I hope somebody can help me in the folowing problem:
Let's say that I have the code:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="Item1.php">Item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item2.php">Item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="Item3.php">Item3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"></div>
```

In order to load the content of Item*.php in div#content when a menu item is pressed I use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('#content').load(the correct file);
    });
});
```

But now I can't press back or forward or see the browser history. So how should I use pushState and popState in order to do these things?

Comment: not clear , what do you mean by history

Comment: I mean html5 history methods like pushState and popState.

Answer (score 0):

here we need to load page content, based on location href, so we will play around that using push/popstate

I did something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(window).bind('popstate', function(event){
        parse_location_href();
    });

    $('a').click(function(){
        history.pushState(null,null, '/correct item php');
        $('#content').load(correct item php);
    });
});

function parse_location_href()
{
    urlParams = get_query_params(); // get which item.php has to be called from query params
    set_form_params(urlParams); // here you update page params/setting (not always required)
    
    $('#content').load(load correct item.php);
}
```

Hope it helps